# What is the benefit of Node Blocks module versus adding content to blocks in body field?

Tags: nodes

What is the benefit of Node Blocks module versus adding content to blocks in body field?

It seems like the functionality is identical?

Either create content, and use it as a block.

Or create a block and add content to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nodeblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeblock)

> This module allows you to specify content type(s) as being a block. This > allows > the content managers of the site to **edit the block text
>   and title without having to access the block administration page.
>   Users only need edit access to that node in order to edit it.**

Also, based on above I imagine that you don't need to assign the block a region and a "display only on url". (I could be wrong, never used this module).

Comment: I am the only one that will do any type of editing, so better to keep native Drupal block functions without that module then?

Comment: yeah, no need for this module if that is the case.